# C# simple html editor - how to search and replace content

Tags: c#, html, string, search, replace

Today i'm working on simple html editor in visual c#. 
My goal is to open pure html file from local drive (Opendialog load into string or load into webbrowser completed) and allow to edit key fragments.

- application should find specific divs and return the full content of that div to textbox or better to combobox (compare to combobox item and show it).
- if i change the textbox (or pick up another item from combobox) application should present changes on webbrowser control.
- Then i need to print this html as is seen on webbrowser control.
- Last thing is to save modified hmtl overwrting original and adding comment with changes at bottom of the html file.

I want to know how to perform search&replace in this project? How to "adress" content of a div?
Better is string searching, indexof, string.replace etc. Or drown into DOM-thing (i don't know both at the moment). 
How to present changes on html preview on webcontrol component? And finally overwrite a file?

Code's examples appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Now i stop on savingthe file, after changes. 
Don't know how to start with saving-overwriting current opened and modified file...

Answer (score 0):

You should use HtmlAgilityPack for that, it makes working with DOM a lot more easier, than parsing it yourself.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

For example, here is how to get all divs

> var elements = hdoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div") /*.Where(.your conditions..))*/;